# Sort in ascending order but keep highest at beginning in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array which looks like this

```
arr = ["#4abc", "#2xyz", "#3pol", "#33pe", "#1bfj", "#11lo", "#2mao"]
```

Each element in the array is associated with a `#n`. Now I want to sort them in ascending order. 
So this is what I do

```
arr.sort( (a,b) => a.match(/#(\d)/)[1] - b.match(/#(\d)/)[1])
```

Gives me the expected output

```
arr ['#1bfj', '#11lo', '#2xyz', '#2mao', '#3pol', '#33pe', '#4abc']
```

But I also want to keep the highest in the beginning such that it looks like this

```
arr ['#4abc', '#1bfj', '#11lo', '#2xyz', '#2mao', '#3pol', '#33pe']
```

Now I know `#4` is the highest that can occur in an array. So this is what I tried

```
arr.sort((a, b) => (a.match(/#(\d)/)[1] === "4") - (b.match(/#(\d)/)[1] === "4") || a.match(/#(\d)/)[1] - b.match(/#(\d)/)[1]);
```

But I don't get the expected output. How can I do this?

Comment: What if there are multiple fours? Should *all* of them be at the beginning or only the highest?

Comment: Why is `33` less than `4`?

Comment: @Andreas I only want to sort by `#n` which means `#` and the `first number`. You can check my regex.

Comment: @trincot all the highest elements should be at the beginning.

Comment: I think you mean first "digit", not first "number". These terms have a different meaning ;-)

Comment: @trincot right! my bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is very long, then it becomes important to get a good time complexity. You can use buckets. In your case there are only four buckets: 4, 1, 2, 3. In that order.

So:

```js
let arr = ["#4abc", "#2xyz", "#3pol", "#33pe", "#1bfj", "#11lo", "#2mao"];

let buckets = [[], [], [], []];
for (let val of arr) buckets[val[1] % 4].push(val);
let sorted = buckets.flat();

console.log(sorted);
```

Note how the `%` operator translates 4 to 0, while leaving 1, 2 and 3 unchanged, which is exactly what you need here.

#### When there are no "#4" in the data... Or higher digits occur

If you would have no "#4" in the data, and you would then want to have the "#3" come first, ...etc, or when there can be higher digits (in the range 0 through 9), then you would need a more dynamic bucket-solution:

```js
let arr = ["#6abc", "#2xyz", "#3pol", "#9pe", "#0bfj", "#11lo", "#2mao"];

let buckets = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]; // 10 buckets
for (let val of arr) buckets[val[1]].push(val);
buckets = buckets.filter(bucket => bucket.length); // remove empty buckets
let sorted = buckets.pop().concat(...buckets); // last comes first
console.log(sorted);
```

All these operations have a *O(n)* time complexity, compared to the *O(nlogn)* time complexity that you get from a call to `sort`. Now, if your data is not extreme in volume, a solution using `sort` will still run faster.

Comment: this looks great but I see you created four buckets presumably for `#1`, `#2`, `#3` and `#4`. I may have a situation where I may not have say `#3`elements in array. So do I need to adjust the buckets accordingly?

Comment: If there are no #3, then this will still work. But if you have no #4, then would you need a different order?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Was testing out with some data. I see your edited answer. Do you think your solution can be made dynamic in the sense it would automatically put anything highest in the beginning? I replaced `#4` with `#7` in the array but your solution gave error.

Comment: That is because you said in the question that 4 would be the highest... What is the range of the digit? 1 through 9? Anyway, I updated the second part to allow for any digit (0...9).

Comment: this is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pop the highest element. Sort the rest. And do array.unshift(highest) which places string to the beginning

Comment: I may have multiple highest elements. So pop() won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Given you want the one beginning with 4 to be the *lowest* ranked (first), you would need to use `!==` instead of `===`:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => (a.match(/#(\d)/)[1] !== "4") - (b.match(/#(\d)/)[1] !== "4") || a.match(/#(\d)/)[1] - b.match(/#(\d)/)[1]);
// simplified:
arr.sort((a, b) => (!a.startsWith("#4") - (!b.startsWith("#4")) || a.match(/^#(\d)/)[1] - b.match(/^#(\d)/)[1]);
```

However, as suggested in the other answer, it's probably much easier to just sort all items normally, then move the last to front.

Comment: right! But I may have multiple `#4` elements. So pop will only remove one. Anyway your solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

your solution works !
simply put your args in a different order (aka backward)

arr.sort( (a,b) => b.match(/#(\d)/)[1] - a.match(/#(\d)/)[1])